# Inconsistent image dimension in Facebook shared dialog, among different users

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk, share, facebook-opengraph

My task is to create a dynamic shared image dialog, based on a user choices in a quiz. Thereafter, the user can post their shared image results onto their own timeline. I have prepared and uploaded all the possible image result combinations in the recommended 1200x630 format onto a live server, so as to fetch the respective shared image by absolute linking later on. The shared dialog must use the full-width layout. The thumbnail layout is not desirable in my scenario.

My choice of tool is JS SDK. I am doing a manual login/share flow, using the share_open_graph method. I have created a custom story[share a quiz], action[share] and object[quiz] into the Facebook App accordingly, as well as getting a successful review approval. Below is the code snippet called when user click on share button:

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'share_open_graph',
    action_type: '{APPNAMESPACE}:share',
    action_properties: JSON.stringify({
        'quiz': {
            'og:type': '{APPNAMESPACE}:quiz',
            'og:url': ''+QUIZ_URI+'',
            'og:title': '{MY TITLE HERE}',
            'og:description': ''+msgStr+'',
            'og:image': '{ABSOLUTE LINK HERE}'+imgStr+'.png?v=2',
            'og:image:type': 'image/png',
            'og:image:width': '1200',
            'og:image:height': '630'
        }
    })
});
```

The problem: the shared dialog tends to show the thumbnail version on certain users, while the full-width 1200x630 version for the rest of the users. This decision of assigning thumbnail/full-width layout to the shared dialog seems arbitrary, but is permanent only to that particular user. After posting the shared link on their timeline, the layout still adapts to whichever layout was assigned during the shared dialog phase.

The attached images are how the shared dialog appears to 2 different users, using the same code. This issue can be replicated with the 2 particular users. This is not an isolated event, as there are other users getting the thumbnail layout, even though my images are prepped at 1200x630. (I realized I can't post images here as I have just signed up on stackoverflow...)

I have tried passing additional properties of 1200 width and 630 height respectively in the code snippet above, but to no avail. I have also tried to manually put the og:image:width, og:image:height meta tags into the head tag, then using the Facebook debugger tool to do a forced scrape. This did not work too.

Please advise, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've just found a similar bug report in facebook at: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/425449337635582